# Generate all combinations of values with set list of values for each character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

I have a dataset that looks like this

| Position | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

And I'd like to generate all combinations of strings with the value at each position.

For this example, the output would look like

| Output |
| --- |
| 185 |
| 285 |
| 385 |
| 186 |
| 286 |
| 386 |

The order doesn't particularly matter.

**Note**: There can be an arbitrary amount of groups and values per group.

The below SQL sets up the sample input.

```
Declare @Table Table 
(
    groupId int, 
    value int
)

Insert Into @Table 
    Select 1,1
    union select 1,2
    union select 1,3
    union select 2,8
    union select 3,5
    union select 3,6

Select 
        * 
    From 
        @Table
```

Comment: I don't understand well the question with the example provided, but if you do really want something related to "all combinations", you must perform a cartessian product. With sql server is using the sintax `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @James The problem with cross join is that (as far as i know) it will not dynamically handle arbitrary amount of groups. I would have to write a cross join for each group.

Comment: This is a good question. My take -- I'm not 100% sure -- is that this cannot be done with a single query; maybe it could be done with a very limited number of groups only. Anyway, since the solution requires an iteration, it seems pretty straightforward to do it with a custom function. Doesn't look to daunting.

Comment: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: @ub_coding 18.6

Comment: There isn't an version 18.6 @Jacob . The latest version is 15.0.4188.2 (Cumulative update 14 (CU14) for SQL Server 2019).

Comment: @Larnu oops - 18.6 is the version of SSMS I'm on. My SQL Version is 2019 15.0.4073.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a recursive CTE for this,** dynamic SQL is not needed

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      1 AS Position,
      CAST(Value AS varchar(100)) AS Value
    FROM #YourTable t
    WHERE Position = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      cte.Position + 1,
      CAST(cte.Value + t.Value AS varchar(100))
    FROM #YourTable t
    JOIN cte ON cte.Position + 1 = t.Position
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Position = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Position FROM #YourTable t2 ORDER BY t2.Position DESC);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84f02e/1)

If there are gaps then you a need a more complex solution:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextValues (@gtThanPosition int)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  t.Position,
  t.Value
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.Position > @gtThanPosition OR @gtThanPosition IS NULL
ORDER BY t.Position;

GO
```

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t.Position,
      CAST(Value AS varchar(100)) AS Value
    FROM dbo.GetNextValues(NULL) t

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      t.Position,
      CAST(cte.Value + t.Value AS varchar(100)) AS Value
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNextValues(cte.Position) t
)
SELECT Value
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Position = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Position FROM YourTable t2 ORDER BY t2.Position DESC);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d2f1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the number of groups, I suspect you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestGroup;

CREATE TABLE #TestGroup
(
    GroupId int,
    Value int
);

INSERT INTO #TestGroup
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 8),
    (3, 5),
    (3, 6)
;

DECLARE @MaxGroup int;
SELECT @MaxGroup = MAX(GroupId) FROM #TestGroup;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ';

DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i <= @MaxGroup
BEGIN
    If @i <> 1 SET @sql = @sql + N', ';
    SET @sql = @sql + FORMATMESSAGE(N'T%i.Value As C%i', @i, @i);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM ';
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= @MaxGroup
BEGIN
    If @i <> 1 SET @sql = @sql + N' CROSS JOIN ';
    SET @sql = @sql + FORMATMESSAGE(' (SELECT Value FROM #TestGroup WHERE GroupId = %i) As T%i ', @i, @i);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

PRINT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestGroup;
```

Output:

```
SELECT T1.Value As C1, T2.Value As C2, T3.Value As C3 
FROM  (SELECT Value FROM #TestGroup WHERE GroupId = 1) As T1  
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT Value FROM #TestGroup WHERE GroupId = 2) As T2  
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT Value FROM #TestGroup WHERE GroupId = 3) As T3
```

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | 8 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is that you have both an arbitrary number of groups. With a static number of groups you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(YT1.[Value],YT2.[Value],YT3.[Value])
FROM dbo.YourTable YT1
     JOIN dbo.YourTable YT2 ON YT1.Position < YT2.Position
     JOIN dbo.YourTable YT3 ON YT2.Position < YT3.Position;
```

As a result, one method would be to use a dynamic solution. Note that without details of what version of SQL Server you are using, I am **assuming** you are using a fully supported version. I also assume you can't have gaps. For example, if `position` `5` were omitted, but `position` `6` wasn't, then you don't expect a `0` for the 5 digit (and `position` `6` would be the 5th digit instead).

This gives you this, which is messy, if I am honest, but does the job:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
WITH DisctinctPositions AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           Position
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
Positions AS(
    SELECT Position,
           LAG(Position) OVER (ORDER BY Position) AS PrevPosition
    FROM DisctinctPositions)
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT CONCAT(' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'YT',P.Position)) + N'.[Value]',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.Position) + N')' + @CRLF +
              N'FROM dbo.YourTable YT1' + @CRLF +
              STRING_AGG(CASE P.Position WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE N'     JOIN dbo.YourTable' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'YT',P.Position)) + N' ON ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'YT',P.PrevPosition)) + N'.Position < ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'YT',P.Position)) + N'.Position' END, @CRLF) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY P.Position)
FROM Positions P;

--PRINT @SQL; Your best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Did I miss something, can you not just do a recursive CTE?

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind, if I am honest, @Charlieface . I didn't say you couldn't though, just that this is one method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```sql
with cte(c, s) as (
  select 2, cast(value AS varchar(100)) from vals where position = 1
  union all
  select c.c+1, cast(concat(c.s,v.value) as varchar(100)) from cte c join vals v on c.c = v.position
)
select c.s from cte c where c.c = (select top 1 v1.position from vals v1 order by v1.position desc) + 1
```